# Quaternion Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, quaternions

Define 
$$ 1 =
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 \\ 
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$ i =
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & -1 \\
    1 & 0 \\ 
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$ j =
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & -i \\
    -i & 0 \\ 
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$ k =
    \begin{bmatrix}
    i & 0 \\
    0 & -i \\ 
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Define

$$ H = a[1]+b[i]+c[j]+d[k]$$

$$ H =
    \begin{bmatrix}
    a+di & -b-ci \\
    b-ci & a-di \\ 
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$ H =
    \begin{bmatrix}
    z & w \\
    -\bar w & \bar z \\ 
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

where $$z= a+di$$
$$w=-b-ci$$

This is the basic quaternion setup we've been taught, my question is the following:

Define $\alpha$, $\beta$ are matrices in the form of $H$. What is $\alpha \cdot \beta$?

For example before we even get to multiplying the two H matrices, what does one H matrix represent in terms of a geometric interpretation? Is it a rotation in $R^4$? Am I even interpreting what the question is asking properly?

Comment: What's wrong with using regular matrix multiplication to find $\alpha\cdot\beta$? They have chosen to represent these as matrices for a reason.

Comment: I think I worded it wrong, $\alpha \beta$ are matrices in the form of $H$, what is the result of multiplying them together. It's just a question the prof has put down and I really can't piece together what he's trying to ask here.

Comment: Looks like he's asking for $\begin{bmatrix}z_\alpha & w_\alpha \\ -\bar w_\alpha & \bar z_\alpha \end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix}z_\beta & w_\beta \\ -\bar w_\beta & \bar z_\beta \end{bmatrix}$. And $H$ is just a quaternion -- no special geometric interpretation other than a point in 4-dimensional space.

Comment: thank you for this